# Ошибка преобразования

Tags: c#, unity3d

Почему высвечивается ошибка CS0029(не получается преобразовать одно в другое)и как мне это сделать?

```
 public class tik_scr : MonoBehaviour
    { 
      public struct dela_emblem
      {
       public int price;
       public Button button;        
      }    
      public dela_emblem[] buttonsArray;
      private Save sv = new Save();

      private void Awake()
      {      
       if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Save"))
      {
       sv = JsonUtility.FromJson<Save>(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Save"));                  
       buttonsArray = sv.buttonsArray;//здесь ошибка
      }

      private void OnApplicationQuit()
      {
       sv.buttonsArray = buttonsArray;//и здесь
       PlayerPrefs.SetString("Save", JsonUtility.ToJson(sv));        
      }
    }               

    [Serializable]
    public class Save
    {
     public struct dela_emblem{public int price;public Button button;}
     public dela_emblem[] buttonsArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас тип `struct dela_emblem` объявлен в двух местах, таким образом, это два разных типа. Уберите его из первого фрагмента.

```
public class tik_scr : MonoBehaviour
{ 
  public Save.dela_emblem[] buttonsArray;
```

Comment: теперь проблема другая(этот отрывок из первого класса)                                                                            
`foreach (dela_emblem item in buttonsArray)//не удалось найти тип или пространство имен"dela_emblem"`

Comment: `public struct` описывается не в классе, а снаружи. А ещё неплохо было бы написать к нему конструктор. ознакомтесь с примерами кода https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-structs

Comment: @Erick Обратите внимание на то, как объявлен массив в ответе. Тип `dela_emblem` описан внутри класса `Save`, поэтому использовать его надо так - `Save.dela_emblem`.

Comment: @Igor это я заметил,но он всё равно не работает. Вот щас сел разбираться дальше с ссылками вверху

Comment: @Erick `foreach (Save.dela_emblem item in buttonsArray)` или `foreach (var item in buttonsArray)`

Comment: @Igor понял,мой поклон

Comment: @Erick На здоровье. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.